# detecting monitor resolution in explorer and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to detect the actual monitor resolution or size using either JQuery or JavaScript, the screen.availWidth or screen.width seem to work in all browsers except for firefox and explorer...

If the window is maximized it will get the information but if the window was scaled down or even zoomed it doesn't give the monitor resolution but looks at the window instead...

I've gone through several posts on here but haven't found anything and I think most of them are not stating the fact that the window size might not be maximized or zoomed when getting the wrong type of information...

I'm hoping there's a solution I'm missing, thanks ahead for any help ;)

Comment: According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.width) it should work

Comment: unfortunately not even tried window.screen.availWidth as mentioned on one of the posts on here and I get the wrong results...

Comment: You can only get the window size in javascript, there is no way to see the monitor resolution.

Comment: @Phaeze - of course there is -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lgqgv8s4/**, and I just tested that, and it works just fine in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Oh wow, did not know about that. You should answer the question, everyone else apparently stopped reading after the first paragraph

Comment: @Phaeze - The OP is actually saying he's using `screen.width`, so posting an answer that is exactly the same as what the OP is using, doesn't really help if it's not working. All I can do is post a comment saying I've tested it, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Just took a look at your link there and it does seem to be working in both in IE and Firefox, except when there was a zoom, this is still a step closer then what I'm getting, trying to figure out why now... Wonder if it's the doctype, I've seen odd results based on that in the past... I'll post it when I figure it out, thanks again for the help...

Comment: PS the zoom makes no difference in any other browser...

Comment: Most humble apologies the code does work in both browsers, I overlooked that fact that I had the windows zoomed as I only had a blank canvas while running my tests and didn’t notice, this does however still pose an issue to what I’m trying to do so does anyone know of any way around this now?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `var x = "Available Width: " + screen.availWidth;`

Comment: That's just assigning the value to a variable, just in case I did try it but no it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery:](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```